# correctly save data of the form (x,y) in a csv file

Tags: python, numpy

I guess this is very rather trivial.
I have a list of x and y values created as follows:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 1001)
y = 3*np.sin(x)**3 - np.sin(x)
```

How can I save the (x,y) values in .csv file, that is, in the form

```
x1, y1
x2, y2
```

etc. I think it has to do with `delimiter` keyword.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 1001)
y = 3*np.sin(x)**3 - np.sin(x)

np.savetxt('filename', np.vstack((x,y)).T, delimiter=', ')
```

This uses [numpy.savetxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) and [numpy.vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) is used to prepare the data.

Default behaviour on arrays of `dtype=np.float64` is using *scientific-notation*. You can control this using the `fmt`-parameter of `numpy.savetxt`.

Default-output looks like:

```
0.000000000000000000e+00, 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000021e-03, -9.999968333348416283e-04
...
```

Comment: Yeah, sry. Happens all the time. :-)   Transpose is used here to change shape from (2,X) -> (X,2).

Answer (score 2):

You can use python csv package to write and save it to a .csv file. Use zip to create a single list of values from both x and y.

```
import csv

new_list = zip(x, y)
with open('file1.csv', 'wb+') as csvfile:
     filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
     filewriter.writerows(new_list)
```